# Markdown `native` text alignment

Tags: markdown

Does `markdown` support *native* text-alignment without usage `html` + `css`?

Comment: For **GitHub Flavored Markdown**, `<p align=center>` works. (from [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43473887/6320039))

Comment: For HTML5, `<p style="text-align:center"> example text </p>`

Answer (score 250, accepted):

[*native* markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) **doesn't** support text alignment without `html` + `css`.

Comment: Therefore wrap your text in `<p style="text-align: center;">` and `</p>` which should work in any markdown

Comment: **Github users:** inline styles do not work on github and are not included as extended features of Github Flavored Markdown. This is [all github supports as of Jan 2017](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/). There are many online markdown testers that say they comply with GFM and show things like inline styles working, but github markdown [pretty much]* doesn't support HTML/CSS at the moment.  *`<br>` works so there might be some hidden tags that work.

Comment: **Github users:** As of *6/8/2017*, Diego Vinícius's answer below successfully centers text in markdown files. Just wrap your text in a `p` tag with `align` set to `center`, like so: `<p align="center">centered text</p>`

Comment: BTW, which would be better to use, `<div>` or `<p>`? A `p` is a paragraph, so maybe `div` would be a more neutral and better alternative?

Comment: @SDJMcHattie This doesn't work when converting .md to .pdf.

Comment: Anybody know _why_ text alignment is such a challenge and/or bad idea for native markdown? Seems like such a strange omission.

Comment: @k3davis alignment is a styling specification. Markdown specifies structure.

Comment: This answer has earned more points than my account...  for a fancy "no." Gotta love it. Btw, anyone else find it ironic that we are using md syntax to discuss md syntax?

Comment: @PeterWood and yet it supports (or is commonly extended to support?) underline, bold, etc. which have nothing to do with structure. the distinction seems arbitrary.

Comment: **In Jupyter notebooks:** Inline styles and style definitions in markdown don't work.  @mdarens native markdown table syntax answer below does work but looks miihh!?  Saying `from IPython.display import *; display(HTML("<style> ... </style>"))` in a code cell **and running it** retroactively affects styles for the whole notebook and lets you define a style class like "div.centered".  Jupyter also has a standard location for a "custom.css" file.

Answer (score 140):

In order to center text in md files you can use the center tag like html tag:

```
<center>Centered text</center>
```

Comment: This method is deprecated in html 5.

Comment: This method works on SquareSpace Markdown blocks, as of August 15th, 2018.

Comment: Which method is now preferred?

Answer (score 60):

The div element has its own alignment attribute, [align](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp).

```
<div align="center">
  my text here.
</div>
```

Comment: Best solution. We can use "justify" in place of "center". Applies to everything inside the div without distorting anything.

Comment: To prevent inline MarkDown syntax within the div from breaking and failing to render, consider adding a blank line after the opening `<div` tag. I have found that to prevent that.

Comment: This is the only solution that works better. Thanks

Comment: this works 2023

Comment: Align attribute is also [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/align) in HTML5.

Comment: not sure I'm getting this to work at present on Github for header lines

Comment: It was deprecated but I believe browsers are still allowing pre HTML5 commands to work.

Answer (score 53):

I known this isn't markdown, but `<p align="center">` worked for me, so if anyone figures out the markdown syntax instead I'll be happy to use that. Until then I'll use the HTML tag.

Comment: the *align* attribute has been deprecated since HTML 4 and obsolete since HTML 5.

Comment: While the above answers did not work, this method successfully centered some text for me **on github**.

Comment: Just tested on github: it works for text, it doesn't work for images.

Comment: if html tags works ,you cant align with with p tag o simple align, give a try with <div class="margin: 0 auto;"> with you image inside the div

Comment: @JindrichVavruska what should be used with Markdown these days instead?

Comment: Alot of places uses markdown or alike it, WhatsApp use fews commands from markdown like bold, italic... its a easy way to format texts without having to use toolsboxes and etc

Answer (score 25):

It's hacky but if you're using [GFM](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#tables) or some other MD syntax which supports building tables with pipes you can use the column alignment features:

```
|| <!-- empty table header -->
|:--:| <!-- table header/body separator with center formatting -->
| I'm centered! | <!-- cell gets column's alignment -->
```

This works in marked.

Comment: How would one go around this to apply for a heading? If I use a plain "#" inside the "|" it appears verbatim.

Comment: This only appears to work for text. I'm trying to center an image.

Answer (score 14):

In Github You need to write:

```
<p align="justify">
  Lorem ipsum
</p>
```

Comment: I like to start longer README.md files with an "Index" listing. I put this at the end of each section in case readers wanna pop back up to the index `<p align="right">[Index](#index)</p>` Works great :)

Comment: This solution works, but some styles like italic text are lost.

Comment: @JavDomGom try adding a blank line after the opening `<div` tag, then your inline element styles should be preserved.

Comment: Align attribute is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/align) in HTML5.

Answer (score 8):

For [Markdown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#spe-attr) you can use custom attributes:

```
# Example text {style=text-align:center}
```

This works for headers and blockquotes, but not for paragraphs, inline elements and code blocks.

A shorter version (but not supported in HTML 5):

```
# Example text {align=center}
```

Comment: @AlmostPitt As mentioned, it's a Markdown Extra specific feature, it's not likely to work elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

A qualified 'yes' using table syntax. For example, you can center-align plain text as follows:

```
| |
| :-: |
| Excerpts from Romeo and Juliet (arr. V. Borisovsky) |
```

This yields:

|  |
| --- |
| Excerpts from Romeo and Juliet (arr. V. Borisovsky) |

Note that you can still use Markdown inside an HTML block. For example:

```
<div style="font-style: italic; text-align: center;" markdown="1">

## Excerpts from Romeo and Juliet (arr. V. Borisovsky)
### Sergei Prokofiev
#### Timothy Ridout, viola ∙ Frank Dupree, piano

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found pretty useful to use latex syntax on jupyter notebooks cells, like:

```
![good-boy](https://i.imgur.com/xtoLyW2.jpg  "Good boy on boat")

$$\text{This is some centered text}$$
```

Comment: This works as most markdown library support Latex

Answer (score 3):

For most markdown parsers, there is no way to natively align text.
A few parsers support this syntax: `-> centered <-`.

But, if your parser doesn't support it, you can use HTML for that, even allowing you to render markdown inside the tags.

When using any element such as a title, you can use an equivalent html tag, for instance

```markdown
# Title
## title 2
```

is equivalent to

```html
<h1> Title </h1>
<h2> Title 2 </h2>
```

With title, for instance, you can align the text using the following attribute:

```html
<!-- title only -->
<h1 align="center"> Title </h1>

<!-- title with div -->
<div align="center"> <h1 align="center"> Title inside div! </h1> </div>
```

But sometimes you don't want to use HTML, because it butches the capability of using markdown inside it, in these cases, you can use span, which allows you to render markdown inside HTML tags:

```html
<!-- title with span (you can render emojis or markdown inside it) -->
<span align="center"> <h1> :star: ~~Centered~~ </h1> </span>
```

Please note that this attribute is deprecated, while it's deprecated, it is also the only one that works with some flavors of markdown, such as Github's markdown

Answer (score 2):

For [python markdown with attr_list extension](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/attr_list/) the syntax is a little different:

```
{: #someid .someclass somekey='some value' }
```

Example:

```
[Click here](http://exmaple.com){: .btn .btn-primary }

Lead information paragraph
{: .lead }
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Readme file of Github** Using `div` can center everything-

```
<div align="center">
    Any Text/Card/Item
</div>
```

but using `p` this way doesn't help for all item-

```
<p align="center">
    Any Text/Card/Item
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this for headers

```
# <center>Title</center>
```

This will center your header "title"

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to center an image and none of the techniques suggested in answers here worked. A regular HTML `<img>` with inline CSS worked for me...

```
<img style="display: block; margin: auto;" alt="photo" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/images/image.jpg">
```

This is for a Jekyll blog hosted on GitHub

Answer (score -15):

To center align, surround the text you wish to center align with arrows (`->` `<-`) like so:

```
-> This is center aligned <-
```

Comment: I'm test this option in some online Markdown. Can you add an URL or tell us in wich Markdown this sentence work?

Comment: This works in Discount (http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/), a C implementation of the original markdown.

Comment: And also in [RDiscount](http://rubygems.org/gems/rdiscount) its `ruby` implementation. Thanks!

Comment: You have to add this plugin to have this working: https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it-center-text

Comment: Doesn't work in Notepad++ (python markdown + Live HTML plugin)

Comment: @PierreArlaud Sorry for being OT, but: Does Redmine actually support markdown? I've been waiting for ages for this app to support MD ....

Comment: @Bunjip Like everyone else, I guess they just did whatever they wanted so that their format looks like a markdown dialect…

Comment: @PierreArlaud Alright, that's my impression, too. Having been around for many years now, RN probably has started even before the markdown trend has started. Guess, folks at RedNotebook would still call there style 'Rich Text Format' or such. Nevemind, with real md support and a fresh and modern UI, RedNotebook could become an awesome tool even these days - [as I've imagined the other day](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/journal-and-note-taking-desktop-app-for-ubuntu-with-markdown-support-modern-dis)

Comment: This answer was really helpful, because I was looking for an elegant syntax to centre text (and perhaps blocks of text). Thanks for this!