# Position a markdown table centered on page

Tags: css, markdown, doxygen

In a C project, Doxygen is used to include a markdown style table, like:

```
|A|B|C|
|--:|:-:|:-:|
|aaa|bb|c|
|aa|b|ccc|
|a|bbb|cc|
```

I want to center the whole table horizontally.
Note that this is *not* about aligning the text in its cells, but about the table as a whole.

---

Thanks to @Waylan, I understand this is a matter of adding the correct css styles.

So my question boils down to: how can I add css to a doxygen project? And how can I add a css class to a doxygen block?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Markdown \`native\` text alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051715/markdown-native-text-alignment)

Comment: You need to use CSS to style the HTML generated by Markdown.