# R: how to center output in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I know I can set `fig.align = 'center'` if I want to center my figure. But what if I want to center my output in a pdf document?

Comment: do you want HTML or PDF output? (The answers will differ.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051715/markdown-native-text-alignment/34859340#34859340

Comment: PDF output. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: does putting `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` around your code chunk work?  (I don't know if it will, but it's worth a try.)

Comment: That didn't work for me

Comment: Did you put chunk between begin and end ? In my env, `\begin{center}` text  `\end{center}` works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following code worked for me.

```
\center Centered Text \center
```

And, if you need to put it in **bold**, as my case, you can use the underline (two at the beggining, two at the end):

```
\center __Centered Text__ \center
```

Comment: For using within a chunk, I had to escape the `c` so used `\\center ` instead.

Comment: I tried the code above. It works for the text I put between the two `\center`. However, all the following paragraphs were all centered after I centered the text on the line I planned. Any thought?

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully it is not too late to add my answer.

You can use [html tags](https://html.com/tags/center/) in Rstudio Markdown documents.

To center a text you just need to:

```
<center> TEXT TO CENTER </center>
```

This works for me when knitting Rstudio Markdowns.

Comment: The html tags do not work when I knit PDF in rmarkdown.

Answer (score 2):

The option for centering a plot you generated by R code in Rmd file and that for an existing figure from a file elsewhere is different.

For the figures you generated in R, I think `fig.align="center"` is sufficient, even if you want a PDF output.

For `<center> <\center>` to work, you can only use an HTML output. If you still want PDF output, I think you can use `include_graphics(your_img.png)` from `knitr` package, and then you can use chunk options like `fig.align="center"`. If you also want to change the size of this figure, please use something like `out.width="50%"`, but not `fig.width`.

For more details, I found this article really useful [tips and tricks for working with images and figures in r markdown documents](https://www.zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/#use-dpi-to-change-the-resolution-of-images-and-figures).