# Center text MARKDOWN displayed GITHUB

Tags: github, markdown

I want to display "LDC" and "GRANT" as centered text. It works well on VSCODE in my preview. But at my repository on github it doesn't. I have also tried to put the text between ->text<-.

Here my example:

```
# <center> LDC </center>

## title title title

### <center> GRANT </center> 
**blablablablabalbalbalab**
```

Comment: I saw this topic but didn't pay attention to comments... My bad bois. this command "<p align=center>" fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This fix my problem. Sorry for double topic. Someone has already answered in [Markdown `native` text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051715/markdown-native-text-alignment) in the comments section.