# How to center a text, or a heading, in an RMD file?

Tags: html, r

I have already tried using the `<center>` and `<\center>` and it had worked but only temporarily.

After a few hours of working with the same RMD file, the `<center>` and `<\center>` stopped having its effect. I am not sure why.

But there should be another way because this `<center>` approach is an HTML approach. I am sure there must be some simple approach specifically for RMD files.

Comment: not sure if this will help, but to close an HTML tag, use a forward slash.

Comment: [Native markdown doesn't support text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051715/markdown-native-text-alignment), HTML/CSS is required for that. You can use _e.g._ `<div align='center'>your text</div>`.