# Markdown not working with github pages (didn't convert markdown to HTML)

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I try to make a GitHub page on my repo

but I have a problem, it like that Markdown not working with Github pages
you can my website here: https://ahmedeltabarani.github.io/learnGodotArabic/

if you do `Ctrl + U` to see the source code you will note that it didn't convert markdown to HTML, it just put markdown's raw as a normal text and didn't

the web structure should be like a README.md file in my repo here https://github.com/AhmedElTabarani/learnGodotArabic/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are experiencing problems due to the use of div tags in your markdown. Please see more details here: [Markdown `native` text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051715/markdown-native-text-alignment)

You might want to think about at least using a Jekyll theme and create blog posts over using standard md files. That will give you more flexibility with formatting and using css.