# How to write given html in markdown?

Tags: html, markdown

I want to write

```html
<div style="text-align :center"><code>C = P<sup>e</sup> / n</code></div>
```

in markdown. What is the equivalent in markdown?

Comment: Which version of markdown? It's not the most standardized format in the world. Have you looked up syntax documentation on markdown? What did you find? Did you try to translate it yourself? Did you get stuck? What do you have so far?

Comment: The question is starting from a weird assumption. 
The assumption is that markdown is a standard markup code; it is not!  Depending on the platform you're dealing with, markdown might have been implemented in slightly different flavours. In order to answer your question, you will need to engage with the platform documentation because each platform would have a slightly different solution to your problem.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use tools Like [HTML To MD](https://codebeautify.org/html-to-markdown)

So Your HTML code in MD will Be

```markdown
`C = Pᵉ / n`
```

But according to this [Answer On Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051715/markdown-native-text-alignment)

> [native markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) doesn't support text alignment without html + css.

Markdown doesn't support text alignment without html or css And also cannot use superscript or subscript in Markdown but there are other ways for example:

You Can use websites Like [Superscript and Subscript Numbers](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/superscript-and-subscript-numbers/)  Or [Superscript and Subscript Letters](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/superscript-and-subscript-letters/) and copy whatever character you want and use it

Comment: If I remove text align center how to attain this ?
`<code>C = P<sup>e</sup> / n</code>`